# Is This jQuery Bug On First Option Selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have weird situation with `Select2` plugins :

When, `#state` is changed, it will do ajax request to get list of `#city`. once `#city` is selected, it will do ajax request to get `#area` list.

if I select `#city` option number 2, 3, etc... it will trigger `#area` to get the list. but if I choose option number 1, none will happen.

but once, I choose option number 2, 3, etc... then go back to choose option number 1, then it will run ajax perfectly.

**pic 1 : Badung (option #1) is selected for the first time, not trigerring AJAX to get #area**

[image: Badung is selected for the first time, not trigerring AJAX to get #area]

**pic 2 : Bangli (option #2) is selected, it's trigerring AJAX to get #area**

[image]

**pic 3 : Back to Badung (option #1), now it's trigerring AJAX to get #area**
[image]

here's my HTML structure :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <label class="">State</label>
        <select id="state" class="full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" name="state">
            <option select="selected"></option>

            <?
                for ($i = 0; $i < $num_propinsi; $i++) {
                    $value = $propinsi[$i]['province_id'];
                    $text = $propinsi[$i]['province'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$text.'</option>';
                }
            ?>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <label>City</label>
        <select id="city" class="full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" name="city" disabled>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <label>Area</label>
        <select id="area" class="full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" name="area" disabled>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my jquery :

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#form-flogin").validate();

        $("#state").change(function() {
            $("#city").html("");
            $("#s2id_city").find("#select2-chosen-2").html("");
            $("#s2id_area").find("#select2-chosen-3").html("");
            $("#area").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#flogin-submit").prop("disabled", true);
            var propinsi = $("#state").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "controller/ctrl.getcityarea.php?req=city&val="+propinsi,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(json){

                    var city = "";
                    $.each(json, function(i,o){
                        city += "<option value="+o.id+">"+o.city_name+"</option>";
                    });

                    $("#city").append(city);

                    event.preventDefault();             
                    $("#city").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            })
        });

        $("#city").change(function() {
            $("#area").html("");
            $("#s2id_area").find("#select2-chosen-3").html("");
            var city = $("#city").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "controller/ctrl.getcityarea.php?req=area&val="+city,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(json){

                    var area = "";
                    $.each(json.rajaongkir.results, function(i,o){
                        area += "<option value="+o.subdistrict_id+">"+o.subdistrict_name+"</option>";
                    });

                    $("#area").append(area);

                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#area").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });

        $("#area").change(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#flogin-submit").prop("disabled", false);
        });
    })
</script>
```

any idea why `.change` method is not working on first attempt? but works on next attempt. thank you for your help

Comment: Small typo `<option select="selected"></option>` here `select` should be `selected`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 : thanks for your information, bro. but that's not cause the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have written a change event listener for city dropdown and first city is default selected hence when you select it again it won't change the value therefore change event listener won't get fire.

You can do one of following two options

Option 1 : put extra option as "Select City" and then select first city of your choice.

```
$("#city").append("<option value=''>Select City</option>");
$("#city").append(city);
```

Opetion 2 : trigger change event through code

```
$("#city").append(city).change();
```

Comment: both options works, bro. thanks a lot. but I like the second one. because it doesn't have additional option to select.

Comment: happy to help you :)